# How do you upload an image to blogger for use in a custom button

Tags: blogger

According to all the tutorials I've found, if you want to add links to your Facebook/Twitter/Pinterest etc from your blogger.com blog, you use custom HTML with the img src for each button set to a funky looking URL that looks like it might not last (in other words might not be a permalink).

How do you upload an icon-sized image to blogger for use in a custom button and be confident that the URL to the image won't change and break your button?

Answer (score 0):

You could just upload it into some post, switch to the HTML view and copy the link after `

How should an URL break? Usually they're pretty constant.

But you could also create the links without the use of images at all, using Bootstrap and CSS only, if you're interested, I just recently wrote a tutorial on how to achieve that: http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/2013/09/css-social-media-buttons-and-hover.html (sorry for the self advertisement)

Answer (score 0):

Be default,all the pictures you upload in blogger are stored at [Picassaweb(now Google+)](http://picasaweb.google.com/)

If you want to have an image upload just go to [Picassaweb(now Google+)](http://picasaweb.google.com/) and upload.And you need not worry about anything